# Accessing method anytime on certain input

Tags: c#

I'm writing a simple text adventure, and would like to have a main menu, which can be accessed at any time, while any other method is running just by typing "menu" in the console

Here's some code that I wrote (sorry, if it's not very good, I'm only starting to learn), but in this example the menu can be accessed only once at the beginning, while I'd like it to run anytime i type "menu", no matter which part of the program is currently running

So, is there any simple and efficient way to check for certain input ("menu" in this case) without copy pasting menu call method everywhere?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance

(This is my previous attempt, which doesn't work, my new approach is in UPDATE1)

```
class Program
{

    static int menuSwitch = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the test program");
        string menu = "menu";
        string trymenu = Console.ReadLine();

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main menu");
            Console.WriteLine("1.Entry1 \n2.Entry2");
            Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out menuSwitch);
            switch (menuSwitch)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Entry1");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Entry2");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Exiting menu");
                    break;
            }
            break;

        } while (trymenu == menu);

        {
            Start();
            Continue();
            End();
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE1

So, I've done some tinkering and managed to get it working as intended, keeping in mind Alejandro's advice, however as I expected, now I have to call the Menu method after every step (console messages in this case) of another (Start) method

I've been wondering if there is any workaround for this, or any other efficient method to check if there is a "menu" input, as it seems kind of excessive and tedious to work with the way it is now

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Start();
    }

    static void Menu()
    {
        int menuSwitch = 0;

        string menu = "menu";
        string trymenu = Console.ReadLine();

        if (trymenu == menu)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main menu");
            Console.WriteLine("1.Entry1 \n2.Entry2");
            Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out menuSwitch);
            switch (menuSwitch)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Entry1");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Entry2");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Exiting menu");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    static void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the test program");
        Menu();
        Console.WriteLine("Type 'menu' to access the main menu");
        Menu();
        Console.WriteLine("Message1");
        Menu();
        Console.WriteLine("Message2");
        Menu();
        Console.WriteLine("Message3");
        Menu();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you have such a repeating pattern, it's good to think about extracting it in a separate method, then call that method everywhere instead of your current approach.

Comment: Thank you, managed to get it working using your approach, the problem with excessive "Menu();" lines, however stays for now, you can check my update, if you have some spare time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be to move the common code to a method. You might however want to model your game as a [state machine](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html).

This allows you to separate most of the content from the game logic. This is very useful since it allows you to store the content in some file that can be loaded by the game engine. A very simple state could look something like this:

```
public interface IState
{
    string Description { get; }
    IEnumerable<ITransition> Transitions { get; }
    void OnActivated(IState from);
}
public interface ITransition
{
    string Command { get; }
    IState TargetState { get; }
}
```

In this model commands are modeled as transitions between states. There are several ways to have transitions that are global:

- Make a base class that contains global transitions that all states should have
- Add the global states explicitly when creating each state (probably with some helper method)
- Built the global transitions directly into the main game loop

An example of the last alternative could be something like this:

```
public class Game
{
    private readonly IState initialState;
    private readonly IEnumerable<ITransition> globalCommands;
    private readonly IState exitState;

    public Game(IState initialState, IEnumerable<ITransition> globalCommands, IState exitState)
    {
        this.initialState = initialState;
        this.globalCommands = globalCommands;
        this.exitState = exitState;
    }

    private IEnumerable<ITransition> GetTransitions(IState state) => state.Transitions.Concat(globalCommands);

    public void Loop()
    {
        var currentState = initialState;
        while (currentState != exitState)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(currentState.Description);
            var transitions = GetTransitions(currentState).ToList();
            foreach (var transition in transitions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(transition.Command);
            }

            ITransition nextTransition;
            do
            {
                var command = Console.ReadLine();
                nextTransition = transitions.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Command.Equals(command));
            } while (nextTransition == null);

            nextTransition.TargetState.OnActivated(currentState);
            currentState = nextTransition.TargetState;
        }
    }
}
```

One complexity with this is that you probably want to return to whatever state you left when you exit the menu. One way to do this could be to save the state you entered the menu from in a "exit" transition:

```
public class MenuState : IState
{
    public string Description { get; }
    IEnumerable<ITransition> IState.Transitions => Transitions.Concat(new[] {exit});
    public List<ITransition> Transitions { get; } = new List<ITransition>();
    private Transition exit;
    public virtual void OnActivated(IState from) => exit = new Transition("exit", from);
    public MenuState(string description) => Description = description;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, separating game logic from the content in external file does sound very appealing! However, I don't think that I could handle such a task at my current level, since I've never tried using states and interfaces before, but I'm willing to try it out later some time

Also your way of approaching this seems quite smart and efficient, so even if I don't exactly understand everything at the moment, I'll be sure to check out your link, try to run your code and try to learn what it consists of and how to use it, thank you once more